# how to update a column with multiple values except particular values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
tUser table is having values
```

`UserID`  `UserName` `Email` `isActive`

#### ---------------------------------------------

#### `1`      `abc`  `abc@gmail.com` `1`

#### `2`      `abc`  `abc@gmail.com` `1`

#### `3`      `abc`  `abc@gmail.com` `1`

#### `4`      `abc`  `abc@gmail.com` `1`

#### `22`      `cd`  `cd@gmail.com` `1`

#### `23`      `cd`  `cd@gmail.com` `1`

#### `24`      `ef`  `ef@gmail.com` `1`

#### `25`      `ef`  `ef@gmail.com` `1`

The values are duplicate of UserName `abc`.

I have a query to update isActive column of UserName 'abc'.

```html
UPDATE dbo.tUser
SET isActive = 0
FROM Duplicates d,dbo.tUser
WHERE d.UserId =dbo.tUser.UserId
and d.RN>1
```

But it is updating the first column of UserName 'abc'. I need to keep a particular userID '4' as 1 and other values to update with 0. How can i do it?

If i need to include 4,23 and 25. How can i do it?
i tried with

```html
;WITH Duplicates AS
(
    
        SELECT [UserId],[UserName],[Email],
 RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY[UserName],[Email] ORDER BY [UserName],[Email])
 from dbo.tUser
   
)

UPDATE U
SET isActive = (case when U.UserId IN (4,23,25) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Duplicates d 
JOIN dbo.tUser U
ON d.UserId =U.UserId
and d.RN>1
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you can just use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE u
    SET isActive = (CASE WHEN u.UserId = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM Duplicates d JOIN
         dbo.tUser u
         ON d.UserId = u.UserId
    WHERE d.RN > 1;
```

Note:  Learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @godon Linof.. I have edited my question. could you please have a look

Comment: @Sarat . . . You would use an `in` instead of `=` in the `case`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what is `d.RN`? What is the structure of the `Duplicates` table? Is it possible that `Duplicates.UserId` may contain an Id that is similar to `tUser.UserId` yet refer to a totally different record?

The following script will work for you (however it's not fully tested as I don't have an IDE and SQLFiddler seem to be down:

```
UPDATE u
SET u.IsActive = 0
FROM dbo.tUser u
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT UserId, RANK() OVER (Partition [UserName], [Email] ORDER BY [UserName], [Email]) AS RNK) d
    ON d.UserId = tUser.UserId
WHERE d.RNK > 1
```